# paginating habtm relations

Tags: cakephp, has-and-belongs-to-many

got this situation. Reports habtm users. So Im trying to paginate just the Reports that are linked to the Auth user... I read when you have a habtm relationship you have to bind the model temporarily using 'hasOne' like this:

```
function index(){
$conditions=array('ReportsUser.user_id'=>$this->Auth->User('id'), 'ReportsUser.report_id'=>'Report.id');
$this->beforeFind();
$this->Report->recursive=0;
$this->set('reports',$this->paginate($conditions));
}

function beforeFind()
{
$this->Report->bindModel('hasOne'=>array('ReportsUser'), false);
}
```

so here is the issue... **that doesn't work**...
that give me no results... I already checked the database for user having any Report, and i logged in with one of those user...

any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GOT IT!!

```
$conditions=array('ReportsUser.user_id'=>$this->Auth->User('id'), 'ReportsUser.report_id'=>'Report.id');
```

i just had to remove 'ReportsUser.report_id'=>'Report.id' cuz cake was searching for it for a second time... so i just left

```
$conditions=array('ReportsUser.user_id'=>$this->Auth->User('id'));
```

and i add

```
$this->Report->bindModel('hasOne'=>array('ReportsUser'**=>array('className'=>'ReportsUser', 'foreignKey'=>'report_id')**), false);
```